# Spring security redirecting to login with valid token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

Good afternoon guys, I'm new to spring boot and created an application using jhipster. But for now i'm trying to authenticate using an authorization server (Keycloak) on my angular app, getting the token and when i try to fetch any resource, it redirects me to a kind of login page

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myurl.com/oauth2/authorization/oidc' (redirected from 'https://myurl.com/api/configuracaos/1') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

And after accessing this url directly, it works like a charm. I guess this URL is implemented automatically by Spring and creates an in memory session, but i couldn't find any way to fix this.

Here is my securityConfiguration:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
        .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
            .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
        .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/idiomas").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .and()
            .oauth2Login()
        .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthorityExtractor)
                .and()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Thanks for your time guys! Hope you can help me

Comment: If you're using JHipster, everything is already integrated together so the authentication flow happens on the backend. Moving the flow to the front end is possible, but it's more work, and less secure.

Comment: Yes, i know. the thing is: we have 3 different environments. Backend, frontend(another server) and mobile. Could you guide me how to do this authentication, or any doc? It could be a service at the backend to do the request and create the session without any problem. Thanks!

Comment: my biggest problem is: 
when it passes trough authenticated() it redirects to .../oidc (it probably checks and creates the session), but when i do any request with the token (acquired from keycloak), it says something like: "preflight request redirect is not allowed"

Comment: JHipster is automatically configured to be a resource server, so if you're able to get an access token, you should be able to send it in an `Authorization` header and it'll go through. The React Native and Ionic modules for JHipster leverage this feature.

Comment: It's what i thought, but for some reason it redirects me to /oauth2/authorization/oidc even if i send the token. If i access this URL on the browser, the requests work fine, otherwise they are redirected. I couldn't understand why. But thanks anyway, you answered my question, it was supposed to work with the token without problem. Thanks!!